# QUnit mouseover test

Tags: jquery, asp.net, qunit

I have asp.net button and I want to create a QUnit test that will first create  mouseover and then show an alert. How to do this. I tried

```
test("mouseover",function(){
  $("#buttonid").mouseover(function () {
                        alert('mouseover');
test(true,"Done");
});
                    });
```

but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I used Qunit.trigger event and it solved my issue.

Thanks all.